# Wordpress Subdomain with menu from domain

Tags: wordpress

I am working on a multilanguage website, with different domains (eg: abcd.com and abcd.de) and with different Wordpress instances.
Each have subdomains (e.g. blog.abcd.com, etc).
Is it possible to change the menu for the domains and be visible in the subdomain?
I'm using Wordpress Multisite network for subdomain.

Comment: Sure. Go to menu and set a items of the menu with the link that you want.

Comment: @MarcoRomano-StudioIGS, I already know this (Appearance > Menu > Custom Links). I'd like the menu from domain to show in the subdomains. More, when I make a change in the domain menu, I'd like for it to also be applied on the subdomain.